# Facebook like/share button count consistently resets after a while, why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

I have an iframe FB like/share button. Once I like it, it stays at 1 but after a few hours it always resets to 0. If I press one of my like/share buttons that other people liked successfully (25), the counter resets to 0!

```
<iframe
src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={urlencoded_url_here}&amp;width=135&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=21"
scrolling="no"
frameborder="0"
style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:135px; height:21px;"
allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Why does this happen?

Additional information:

- My URL has a hashbang #! and I treat ?_escaped_fragment_= properly in PHP.
- I do not use an APP ID (made the prototype button while logged in with no APPs created).
- It is for a WP plugin so it needs to work everywhere and I can't make very specific adjustments about the URLs apart from encoding them for the button.
- Like/share count loss happened to me 1-2 months ago for the first time.

Currently I'm testing that in the past FB didn't encode `!` character to `%21` but now when I paste an URL containing `#!` the "Get code" part shows that they encoded exclamation mark as well. JS and PHP doesn't do this with their `encodeURIComponent()` and `urlencode()`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug at Facebook currently, which affects the share count values/consitency.

Have a look at the bug report here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/684361601632430